# Given a background color, black or white text?

Tags: php, css, colors, hex

I'm trying to find a method for determining whether to use black or white text, given a background color (as a hex value). Has anyone dealt with this before? Is there an effective way to do this?

In my case, I would be using PHP to implement the logic (though any experience with this in other languages is welcome).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Take a look at this page: [Calculating Color Contrast with PHP](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2008-09/18-calculating_color_contrast_with_php)

Keep in mind that if black and white are your only choices you're bound to have cases where neither of them works particularly great.

Comment: +1 Calculating the luminance or brightness of the color is far superior to averaging the RGB values.  #FF0000 is bright red, not a dark color that the average of 85 would lead you to believe.  In the HSB system (0-100% scale for B), you get B=100 for bright red.  In the Lab system, you only get 54, probably more useful, since it's above the 50% point, indicating that you should use black against it, not white.

Comment: Beware: the formula in the splitbrain.org article is from an early <a href="https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20060427/#G18">working draft of WCAG 2.0 techniques</a>. The formula and required ratio changed in the  final version.

Answer (score 50):

### Luminosity Contrast algorithm

I think the **best way is the `Luminosity Contrast` algorithm**:

```
function getContrastColor($hexColor)
{
        // hexColor RGB
        $R1 = hexdec(substr($hexColor, 1, 2));
        $G1 = hexdec(substr($hexColor, 3, 2));
        $B1 = hexdec(substr($hexColor, 5, 2));

        // Black RGB
        $blackColor = "#000000";
        $R2BlackColor = hexdec(substr($blackColor, 1, 2));
        $G2BlackColor = hexdec(substr($blackColor, 3, 2));
        $B2BlackColor = hexdec(substr($blackColor, 5, 2));

         // Calc contrast ratio
         $L1 = 0.2126 * pow($R1 / 255, 2.2) +
               0.7152 * pow($G1 / 255, 2.2) +
               0.0722 * pow($B1 / 255, 2.2);

        $L2 = 0.2126 * pow($R2BlackColor / 255, 2.2) +
              0.7152 * pow($G2BlackColor / 255, 2.2) +
              0.0722 * pow($B2BlackColor / 255, 2.2);

        $contrastRatio = 0;
        if ($L1 > $L2) {
            $contrastRatio = (int)(($L1 + 0.05) / ($L2 + 0.05));
        } else {
            $contrastRatio = (int)(($L2 + 0.05) / ($L1 + 0.05));
        }

        // If contrast is more than 5, return black color
        if ($contrastRatio > 5) {
            return '#000000';
        } else { 
            // if not, return white color.
            return '#FFFFFF';
        }
}

// Will return '#FFFFFF'
echo getContrastColor('#FF0000');
```

**Some results:**

[image]

> **NOTE:** *The font color is determined by the previous function. The number in brackets is the contrast ratio.*

---

## YIQ algorithm (less precise)

Another **simpliest and less precise way** called `YIQ` (*because it converts the RGB color space into [YIQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ)*):

```
public function getContrastColor($hexcolor) 
{               
    $r = hexdec(substr($hexcolor, 1, 2));
    $g = hexdec(substr($hexcolor, 3, 2));
    $b = hexdec(substr($hexcolor, 5, 2));
    $yiq = (($r * 299) + ($g * 587) + ($b * 114)) / 1000;
    return ($yiq >= 128) ? 'black' : 'white';
}
```

Comment: Here's a compressed version, if you can supply the *`R`/`G`/`B`* values (out of 255) :  **`function textColor($r,$g,$b) { return ((0.2126*$r/255)+(0.7152*$g/255)+(0.0722*$b/255)>=0.5?'#000':'#FFF'); }`**

Comment: I've adapted the first function to Python if anyone is looking for it : https://gist.github.com/Benbb96/e7b1ce654f616da08e61fa888e666354

Comment: @Benbb96 Good job

Comment: Beware: the luminosity contrast algorithm used here is based on an early [working draft of WCAG 2.0 techniques](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20060427/#G18"). The formula and required ratio changed in the final version.

Answer (score 8):

```
  function getTextColour($hex){
    list($red, $green, $blue) = sscanf($hex, "#%02x%02x%02x");
    $luma = ($red + $green + $blue)/3;

    if ($luma < 128){
      $textcolour = "white";
    }else{
      $textcolour = "black";
    }
    return $textcolour;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an algorithm that can be used to calculate a luminosity contrast ratio of your text:

http://juicystudio.com/services/aertcolourcontrast.php

You could use this formula with white and black values to calculate which gives you the higher ratio, and thus more readable text.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [the CSS Color library](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/). It's implemented in PHP and does all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple but not perfect solution would be to sum the individual components (RGB) and the larger this value the 'lighter the color'. So for a high value you could use black as the foreground, and for a low value, use white.

You could then improve this method, making specific cases for greyscale colors (R = G = B), which, except for very dark grey, won't display white text well.

**Edit:** This of course means you need to know the format of RGB storage in your hex value, standard 24bpp storage is 0x00RRGGBB for the 8 hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

i would calculate the average value of rgb components and then decide whether to use black or white, e.g. white up to 0x66